# My Camera resolution is low

Tags: display-resolution, camera

My camera resolution is low. My `lsusb` output is:

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1903:8328 Generic HD camera
```

And `v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video1 --all` output is:

```
Driver Info:
    Driver name      : uvcvideo
    Card type        : HD camera : HD camera 
    Bus info         : usb-0000:00:1a.7-2
    Driver version   : 5.13.19
    Capabilities     : 0x84a00001
        Video Capture
        Metadata Capture
        Streaming
        Extended Pix Format
        Device Capabilities
    Device Caps      : 0x04a00000
        Metadata Capture
        Streaming
        Extended Pix Format
Priority: 2
Format Metadata Capture:
    Sample Format   : 'UVCH' (UVC Payload Header Metadata)
    Buffer Size     : 1024
```

Comment: You didn't specify what exactly you mean by "low". Which application are you using to access your webcam? How do you know the resolution of the image?
Some suggestions to get objective data:
- Install fswebcam (`sudo apt install fswebcam`).
- Grab an image with fswebcam (`fswebcam -r 1920x1080 test.jpg`)
- Inspect the image (`file test.jpg`)
Does that work? How does the image look when you open it with e.g. gimp?

Comment: From low i mean its a hd camera and its only capturing like 240 px or something

Comment: Which application you are using?

Comment: Chrome Google Chrome